# Regex to clean repetitions of characters

Tags: c#, regex

I have a pattern in the string like this:

`T T` and I want to `T`

And It can be any character from `[a-z]`.

I have tried this [Regex Example](http://regexr.com?31ivh) but not able to replace it.

**EDIT**

Like I have `A Aa ar r` then it should become `Aar` means replace any character 1st or 2nd no matter what it is.

Comment: I don't quite understand the requirement here. You have to characters separated by a space and you only need the first? Or the second? Which language are you using? You don't need a regex for this.

Comment: I think you need to try again - your question is non-sensical

Comment: I have added the pattern in the link posted in the question..and I am using `c#`

Comment: It would be better if your 2 characters were "A B" and then you said you wanted A or you wanted B.. as others have said, what is your code, whys pecifically regexpr will there be many lines.. what did you try?

Comment: I have editted my question and I have also attached a link for whatever I have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the backreferences for this.

```
/([a-z])\s*\1\s?/gi
```

[Example](http://regexr.com?31j03)

Some more explanation:

```
(           begin matching group 1
    [a-z]   match any character from a to z
)           end matching group 1
\s*         match any amount of space characters
\1          match the result of matching group 1
            exactly as it was again
            this allows for the repition
\s?         match none or one space character
            this will allow to remove multiple
            spaces when replacing
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is the meaning of `\1`..??

Comment: It means that the regex tries to copy the exact same result of the first matched group again.
So, say `([a-z])` matches `A` - then, `\1` would try to match exactly `A` and so on.
If you have multiple matching groups, e.g. `([a-z])([0-9])`, you can backreference the result of those groups using `\1`, `\2` etc.

Comment: I added an example that shows the replacement and how it works.